# React Material-UI switch to hide a div

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm new to React and I was wondering how I could hide a div with the Material-UI Switch Input in TS

Comment: please explain more with code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this can solve your problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-taussig-yxey1?file=/src/App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Switch } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch checked={isChecked} onChange={() => setIsChecked(!isChecked)} />
      {isChecked && <div>the element </div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```